# How to unnest an array within an array using SQL (on the Azure Databricks platform)

Tags: sql, arrays, databricks-sql

I'm trying to write a query which accesses values with an array, which is within another array.
My table  is something like this:

SELECT *
FROM my_table

| Column_A | Column_B |
| --- | --- |
| Cell_1 | [{"SubB":[{"first": 1, "second": 2}]}, {"SubB":[{"first": 3, "second": 4}]}] |
| Cell_2 | [{"SubB":[{"first": 5, "second": 6}]}] |

And I am trying to get an exploded flat result accessing values in Column_A and the value with the key "first" so the results look like this:

Results

| Column_A | first |
| --- | --- |
| Cell_1 | 1 |
| Cell_1 | 3 |
| Cell_2 | 5 |

I was trying to use Lateral View Explode like such:

SELECT Column_A, B.SubB
FROM my_table
Lateral View Explode(Column_B) AS B

But to dig into another layer it started to become very hard with subqueries and such.  What's the best way to query an array nested inside another array?

---

Added table creation code:
I finally figured out how to create my_table as a toy dataset using the following.  There probably is a better way but this works:

```
WITH sample1 AS (
SELECT "Cell_1" AS Column_A,
       array(NAMED_STRUCT('SubB', array(NAMED_STRUCT('first', 1,
                          'second', 2))
                          ),
             NAMED_STRUCT('SubB', array(NAMED_STRUCT('first', 3,
                          'second', 4))
                          )
             )            
           AS Column_B
),
sample2 AS (
SELECT "Cell_2" AS Column_A,
       array(NAMED_STRUCT('SubB', array(NAMED_STRUCT('first', 5,
                          'second', 6))
                          )
             )            
           AS Column_B
  ),

my_table AS (SELECT *
           FROM sample1
           UNION ALL (SELECT *
           FROM sample2))

SELECT * 
FROM my_table
```

Comment: Are there really only 2 columns? No ID column? Why bother outputting `---------- ---------`? Please note, in SQL, that you simply CANNOT assume that rows will be processed in any specific order - **unless you specify an order**. With just those 2 columns there is a risk it simply will not work as expected.

Comment: The dashes were unexpected in the stackOverflow formatting, they were meant to indicate the margin between rows.  I'll try to edit that.  Column_B is comprised of arrays (which show with the square brackets) filled with key:Value objects (curly brackets) containing arrays (square brackets again).  Column_A doesn't have nulls, it appears that way only because Column_B ran onto the second line.  I'll edit how that looks, and see what the formatting becomes.

Comment: The db is actually a delta (file?) which databricks shows using SQL commands. It is very nested, and not limited to predefined cell sizes like in structured data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to use more than one lateral view, below the second is used to explode the result of the first lateral view. This should allow access to the nested data as a conventional column.

```
SELECT Column_A, SubBItem.first AS first
FROM my_table
LATERAL VIEW OUTER EXPLODE(Column_B) AS SubBMap
LATERAL VIEW OUTER EXPLODE(SubBMap.SubB) AS SubBItem
```

---

original answer below (question updated since):

Try the following, it contains a "trick" that usually works for SQL Server, using `(select 1)` as the order by seen in the last_value function. This might not work in Databricks or you might need some other approach. However the problem is that SQL tables are considered to be "unordered sets" so your 2 column table, with nulls in column_a, is a problem.

```
SELECT
       CASE WHEN Column_A IS NULL 
              THEN LAST_VALUE(Column_A IGNORE NULLS) OVER (ORDER BY (select 1)) 
               ELSE Column_A 
       END AS Column_A
     , sub_b.first AS first
FROM my_table
LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE(Column_B) AS sub_b
WHERE Column_A <> '----------' /* optional, you decide */
ORDER BY
       Column_A
     , sub_b.first
```

To avoid this type of issue you need to re-consider that 2 column table and find a way to repeat column_a values OR have some other column you can rely on to produce the wanted row order.

Comment: That's a good trick.  I may have misrepresented the table, the column_A didn't have nulls, Column_B was showing across 2 lines.  I changed the table to show the cells correctly.  The Column_B has Arrays filled with objects filled with Arrays (with objects inside that).  The Array within an array is what I am trying to extract using SQL.

Comment: What does this produce? `SELECT Column_A, b.first AS first FROM your_table LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE(Column_B) AS b`  (as I don't have databricks access I cannot test possible options)

Comment: I can't figure out formatting in these comment boxes, but the result from "b.SubB.first"  is an array that looks like "[1,3]"  .

Comment: there is very limited formatting 2 asterisks before and after = **bold** one asterisk = *italics* one backtick berfe and after = `SELECT
 Column_A
, b.SubB.first AS first 
FROM your_table 
LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE(Column_B) AS b`

Comment: That specific query errors with *"Error in SQL statement: AnalysisException: No such struct field first in SubB"* But when I run 

`SELECT Column_A, b.SubB.first AS first
 FROM your_table LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE(Column_B) AS b`

 I Get 

**Column_A | first**  next line ->
**Cell_1 | [ 1, 3 ]**    next line ->
**Cell_2 | [ 5 ]**       next line ->
 
 I hadn't seen this result before. Also I'm extrapolating from my real table, I couldn't create the table using structs and arrays. But this result is a lot closer to what I was looking for.

Comment: I'm lost in your comments. Have you tried the updated (simpler) query at the TOP of my answer above. I only kept the older answer because the comments would be "orphaned:.

Comment: That's it!  I had never seen seen using multiple lateral views like that!  The OUTER was also new to me.  This works!